# VirtualBox macOS Catalina Springboard quit unexpectedly

Tags: ios-simulator, virtualbox, macos-catalina, springboard

I am new to this VirtualBox macOS thing and I am trying to run flutter with the IOS simulator, but when I try to open the IOS Simulator it takes a long time to load and an error comes up and says that the **SpringBoard quit unexpectedly**. I was wondering how I would be able to fix it? I already tried reinstalling it and the error still came up.

```
Process:               SpringBoard [850]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
Identifier:            SpringBoard
Version:               1.0 (50)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [719]
Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [714]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-06-13 18:56:35.137 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.3 (19D76)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        C3FC17E7-DC36-0C9B-B9ED-3D40775A17B0

Sleep/Wake UUID:       48BAAE61-7371-48CE-82D8-E10AFAEE7A5A

Time Awake Since Boot: 3400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [850]

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 704.12.2 - Device: iPhone SE (2nd generation) (E13AD6AD-6437-4A57-B9F4-CAEC3FDBAD36) - Runtime: iOS 13.5 (17F61) - DeviceType: iPhone SE (2nd generation)
```

For the full error: https://pastebin.com/EKJkb5i7

Comment: I am having same error. None of the simulators are working! Just seeing a black screen, tried to reset contents, Xcode settings etc. Nothing seem to be working. :(

Comment: This question and the answers was so helpful. I understand it's not "on topic", but so helpful... I'd argue it is on topic, since an iphone simulator in a virtual machine is a tool primarily primarily for programming, and that is a specific exemption in item 6 of the off-topic examples for stack overflow.

Answer (score 80):

I just had the same issue and solved it by executing the following commands in a Command Prompt with Admin privileges, to disable AVX/AVX2 support for my virtual machine (Make sure to shutdown the VM and close Virtualbox before and replace "YourVMName" with the actual name of your VM in VirtualBox)

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"
VBoxManage setextradata "YourVMName" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX 0
VBoxManage setextradata "YourVMName" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 0
```

Comment: did not work for me somehow... any other ideas?

Comment: HOW did you figure this out

Comment: Thanks! It fixed the simulator.

Comment: Worked for me - thank you!

Comment: Works! Tested using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS host with macOS Big Sur 11.1 guest

Comment: Tried on windows 10. Working for Mac Os Big sur. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me, on ubuntu 20.04 with mac os monterey!. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue with iOS 13.3 simulators. I couldn't solve the problem, but devices with older iOS (I tried with 11.4) working fine. (You can create simulator devices with older iOS in the Device Manager.)

Answer (score 2):

SIGILL usually means you hit a __builtin_trap() or you are trying to execute an instruction that isn't supported by your CPU.

Given this is in some HEVC processing, I suspect your VM is advertising support for some SIMD extension it doesn't actually support (eg: AVX2 or similar).

You should check your VM configuration and ensure it is not advertising support for CPU extensions your system doesn't actually support, and you should file a bug against VirtualPC to ensure they have checks in place to prevent that in the first place.

Comment: What VM configurations should I need to check and change?

Comment: Look for something like "CPU Extensions" or "SIMD" or "AVX" etx